# Fastapi : Showing erorr jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Tags: jinja2, fastapi

I am trying with the below code to redirect to the item page using fast API. I used TemplateResponse to redirect to the index.html page which I already created inside the templates folder.

The file structure is as follows:-

- main

  - app.py
  - templates -> index.html
- static -> style.css

app.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="../static"), name="static")


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/items/{id}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_item(request: Request, id):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "id": id})
```

I tried doing it but I am getting an error "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html" when I insert some HTML code statically it's working but TemplateResponse is not working properly. Even when I tried giving an entire path of the HTML file inside the templates folder it's giving a different error.

Please guide me on how to make this code work as I tried different ways but in any case, this code is giving an error index.html template not found

Comment: Please include your code _in the question_ as text, not as images - images makes it hard to read for those who have trouble seeing, makes it impossible to copy and paste the code to try it, requires the reader to switch between the question and the code, and makes it impossible to search for the code later.

Comment: Include it _in your question_, not as a comment. Comments does not get properly formatted for code.

Comment: Ok i have included the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the template path like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=str(Path(BASE_DIR, 'templates')))
```

Comment: showing same error